# Filter, Sorting and highlight in Datatables Server-Side not working

Tags: datatables

I am using datatables server-side, where i am displaying more then one value in one column.

The problem is, when combining these values (variables) in one column, the sorting and filtering stops working for this column. if i do not use server side, it works perfectly.

Here is my code:

```
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
        "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 7 ] } ],
        "iDisplayLength": 15,
        "aLengthMenu": [[15, 30, 50, -1], [15, 30, 50, "All"]],
        /* Highlight and Unhighlight a search result */
        "searchHighlight": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": './xd_server_side/get_list_of_clients',
        "aoColumns": [
            { mData: 'comp_clients_id' } ,
            { 
                mData: null,
                sClass: "text-left",
                sDefaultContent: "",
                fnRender: function (o) {
                return '<h4><strong>' + o.aData[2] +'</strong></h4><strong>Default Email: </strong>' + o.aData[3] + '<br><strong>Mobile: </strong>' + o.aData[4] + '<br><strong>Address: </strong>' + o.aData[5]
                }
             },
                { 
                    mData: null,
                    sClass: "text-left",
                    sDefaultContent: "",
                    fnRender: function (o) {
                        return o.aData[7]
                    }
                 },
                { mData: 'branch_name' },
                { mData: 'country_name' },
                { mData: 'comp_clients_status' },
                { 
                    mData: null,
                    sClass: "text-left",
                    sDefaultContent: "",
                    fnRender: function (o) {
                    return '<h4>' + o.aData[10] +'</h4>' + o.aData[11]
                    }
                },
                {
                    // This is to add the delete button on each row
                    mData: null,
                    sClass: "text-center",
                    sDefaultContent: "",
                    fnRender: function (o) {
                    var delete_access = user_access == 3 ? 'disabled' : '';
                    return '<a href="crm_clients_edit?cid='+ o.aData[0] + '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit Current Client!" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"' + delete_access + '><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> <a href="#add-address" data-id="'+ o.aData[0] + '" data-clientname="'+ o.aData[1] + '" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary addaddress" data-toggle="modal" ' + delete_access + '>+ <i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> <a onclick="activate('+ o.aData[0] + ', '+ o.aData[2] + ', '+ o.aData[3] + ')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to Change Status!" class="btn btn-xs btn-success statusRow"><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i></a> <a onclick="delete_client('+ o.aData[0] + ')" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to Delete!"id="delRow' + o.aData[2] + '" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delRow" ' + delete_access + '><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>'
                    }
                }
        ],
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
            var sDirectionClass;
            if ( aData[6] == "Active" )
                sDirectionClass = "";
            else
                sDirectionClass = "danger themed-color-dragon";

            $(nRow).addClass( sDirectionClass );
            return nRow;
        }           

    });
```

Comment: When using `serverSide: true` you have to implement the sorting and filtering on the server-side.

Comment: How is that? couldn't find a documentation on that...

Comment: The second sentence in the text [here](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).

Comment: $results = array(
 "sEcho" => 1,
 "iTotalRecords" => count($data),
 "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
 "aaData"=>$data);
 
echo json_encode($results);

Comment: This is the server-side php file:

Comment: We need to see the actual query